# ¿Es correcto usar "hubieron"? ¿Cúal es la diferencia entre "hubo" y "hubieron"?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, conjugación, pretérito

Todos sabemos que el español es muy rico y debido a eso no lo conocemos todo.

A veces menciono la palabra *hubieron* y me la corrigen por *hubo*. Siempre he tenido esta duda: ¿existe *hubieron* o simplemente es una invención del lenguaje? ¿Tal vez es que la utilizo en el contexto inadecuado?

Comment: Claro que existe, es la tercera persona del plural del pretérito perfecto simple  de indicativo del verbo haber.

Comment: @blonfu y por que siempre me lo corrigen?, o es simplemente el contexto en que lo utilizo?

Comment: Es posible que lo estés usando mal, mira estos ejemplos: http://www.rae.es/consultas/hubieron

Comment: Mary: ¿podrías indicar en qué casos usas _hubieron_? Hay algunos que sí son correctos: _cuando hubieron visto la película, se fueron_. El artículo que menciona @blonfu puede serte de mucha ayuda.

Comment: `tal vez es que la utilizo en el contexto inadecuado` Incluye un par de ejemplo de uso en los que alguien te haya corregido. Así la gente podrá decirte "en ese caso se favorece este otro tiempo verbal por esta razón". Sin contexto o ejemplos de uso, es como el chite del tipo que no sabía decir "Federico": "Hubieron" **existe**, lo que hay que estudir/explicar es el uso correcto.

Comment: gracias a todos, **a pesar de que sigo sin entenderlo** los ejemplos señalados por @blonfu fueron útiles, sobre todo la parte donde no debe utilizarse, es de los casos que pedía fedorqui que indicara, estos ejemplos se asemejan bastante a los utilizados por mí.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Hubo* y *hubieron* son dos formas del verbo [haber](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/EsVerbs.aspx?v=haber):

**Hubo:** tercera persona singular del pretérito perfecto simple o pretérito del indicativo
**Hubieron:** tercera persona plural del pretérito perfecto simple o pretérito del indicativo

Se usa [*hubo*](http://www.rae.es/consultas/habia-muchas-personas-ha-habido-quejas-hubo-problemas) (y no *hubieron*):

> Cuando el verbo *haber* se emplea para denotar la mera presencia o
>   existencia de personas o cosas, funciona como impersonal y, por lo
>   tanto, se usa solamente en tercera persona del singular:
>   ❌*Hubieron problemas para entrar al concierto*
>   ✔️*Hubo problemas para entrar al concierto*

Se usa correctamente [*hubieron*](http://www.rae.es/consultas/hubieron):

> Para formar, seguida del participio del verbo que se está conjugando,
>   la tercera persona del plural del tiempo compuesto denominado
>   pretérito anterior o antepretérito de indicativo: *hubieron terminado,
>   hubieron comido, hubieron salido.*

Y también:

> Como forma de la tercera persona del plural del pretérito perfecto
>   simple o pretérito de indicativo de la perífrasis verbal *haber de* +
>   infinitivo, que denota obligación o necesidad y equivale a la más
>   usual hoy *tener que* + infinitivo: *El director y su equipo hubieron de
>   recorrer muchos lugares antes de encontrar los exteriores apropiados
>   para la película.*